# how to return a string from function in c

Tags: c

Im helping my friend in is H.W and i got a weird blackout.
I'm using a function which designated to "decrypt" a message from a given string, the process is working fine(i debugged that to check) but i forgot how to return the value from the function to the main program
I have not touched in C lang for a while so im little blacked out here

Code(Edited):

```
    void func(char* str, char* new_str, int i, int k) {
    if (i < strlen(str)) {
        if ((str[i] >= 'a' && str[i] <= 'z' || str[i] >= 'A' && str[i] <= 'Z')) {
            new_str[k] = str[i];
            func(str, new_str, i + 1, k + 1);
        }
        else {
            func(str, new_str, i + 1, k);
        }
    }
}


int main()
{
    char str[100] = "l#e%i&n^&%a^&%D$%o#@T(r*e^^t*t(e%$L"; //Iterate from end to start.
    char new_str[100] = ""; //Use k index here.
    func(str, new_str, 0, 0);
    printf("%s", new_str);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `char* func(...` but the data will already be in `new_str` so there's not much of a point in returning it. Are you usre it works though? `new_str` isn't initialized so it isn't guaranteed to be properly terminated when you use `strrev` on it, and since this is recursive you'll end up reversing the string many times.

Comment: Actually he told me that he cant use pointers

Comment: `char str[]` is effectively a pointer.

Comment: the code have been edited

Comment: _Side note:_ Is there some reason to call `strlen` for each [recursive] invocation? In fact, why call `strlen` at all? It is very slow. Just replace with `if (str[i] != 0)`

Answer (score 1):

You return a pointer (reference) to the first character of the string.

```
char* someFunction() {
  char* newString = malloc( sizeof( char ) * 13 );
  strncpy( newString, "hello world!", 12 );
  newString[12] = '\0';
  return newString;
}
```

If your string can't be modified (because it is hard-coded) return a `const char*`

```
const char* someFunction2() {
  return "hello world!";
}
```

In both of these cases, the returned value is an address, pointing to a char.  The C-convention of the first `'\0'` character terminating the string is what is used to find the end of the string.

Comment: sorry i dont understand this example, can u do it on my code?

Comment: @OsherRevach If you don't understand the example, please detail what about it is confusing to you.  If you want a person to write it for you, please hire out the work to a contract for-hire programmer; as working with pointers in C can cause tons of issues in the hands of people who don't know the basics.  Personally, I'd recomment you read up on pointers, as C programs will use them heavily (especially when dealing with strings).

Answer (score 0):

I would not make the function return anything at all

pass a pointer to it like this:

```
void func(char* str, char* new_str, int i, int k)
```

and then override new_str[] in the function.
Also, remember that char[10] initializes an array of 10 chars, so if anything you must return a pointer char*, not a single char.

Comment: Okay i used it but i still cant see any print in the console

Comment: you need to inlcude <stdio.h> and <string.h>, then the code compiles and works.